# Pdflib6 for arabic ligature

Tags: pdf-generation, arabic, pdflib, arabic-support

I use Pdflib 6 for generating PDF in Arabic.

I can not get the correct texts (I get the words without ligature.)

I know that with PDFlib 8 & 9 we can use

> new shaping(
>           "tahoma",
>           "shaping script=arab features={liga}",
>           "With optional ligature: features={liga}",
>           "ﻟﻠﻪ"),

to get the ligature. Unfortunately I can't change my version of PDFlib and we can't use **shaping** in current version.

So I'd like to ask if I have other solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

for shaping, it's required to use PDFlib 8 or newer. There is **no** solution in the old and outdated PDFlib 6. So the you have to force updating to the current version of PDFlib 9.